# How to read textbox, and create an action from the click of a button using PyQt5 with a form created in QDesigner

Tags: python, pyqt, designer

I've created  a small form (1 button, 2 textboxes and 1 label) using QDesigner, and converted it to Python.

I can show the form using Python but I don't know how to click the button and show the result of adding the values in the 2 textboxes, on the label.

The code that shows the form is this:

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


Form, Window, Button = uic.loadUiType("PYQT_TUTORIAL.ui")

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
form = Form()


form.setupUi(window)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: share the PYQT_TUTORIAL.ui

Comment: Any idea on how to do that!? Sorry but the file is huge, it exceeds the maximum character limit by over 1000 characters...

Comment: Or do you prefer the .py class file generated from the .ui!?

Comment: Surely your .ui has many components, I recommend creating a new .ui that has a single textbox and button so the .ui should have fewer lines.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it guys, thanks any way.
I was using a main.py to run the PYQT_TUTORIAL.py (that contained the entire form), without need. I just inserted the code to read the text boxes inside the class that contains the form, and that's it.
To many steps for something very simple.

Any questions just let me know, i'll try to explain better.